# loop in string and add some chracter without build in function and es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop, while-loop

how to loop through "string" and add some character between them by an old-style technique without built-in function and es6

```
the input: "446697"
output: "44669-7"
```

add `dash` bewtwen `odd` numbers

---

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Don't be afraid of ES6+, best to use the latest and greatest version of the language for ease of coding and transpile down to ES5 during your build process

Comment: @CertainPerformance i was not afraid to use es6 but  the rule to code at my camp not use it to code, that is why i want to know how to do old-style code,

Answer (score 5):

```
var input = '446697';
for(i=0;i<input.length;i=i+2){
    if(parseInt(input[i]) % 2 !== 0 && parseInt(input[i+1]) % 2 !== 0){
        input.slice(0, i) + '-' + input.slice(i);
    }
}
```

you can use substring as well instead of slice